# Finding sequence of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sequence

I have a table like this:

```
id             date        
1             2018-01-01 01:01
2             2018-01-02 14:00
3             2018-01-01 05:00  -- affected
4             2018-01-03 16:0
```

i wanted to search the sequence of dates (by loop) whether is in ascending order or not, if no, then insert to another table like this:

also inserted the previous and next value of the affected dates.

```
 id             date        
    2             2018-01-02 14:00
    3             2018-01-01 05:00  
    4             2018-01-03 16:00
```

Can you guys help me on this? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you find the error row, then just get the row before and after.

If the id is not continuous, then use `row_number()` to generate the continuous sequence no

```
; with 
tbl as      -- sample data
(
    select id = 1, date = '2018-01-01 01:01'    union all
    select id = 2, date = '2018-01-02 14:00'    union all
    select id = 3, date = '2018-01-01 05:00'    union all
    select id = 4, date = '2018-01-03 16:00'
),
cte as      -- the query
(
    select  *,
            prev    = LAG (date) OVER (ORDER BY id),
            seq     = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)   -- added this
    from    tbl t
),
err as      -- the error rows
(
    select  *
    from    cte
    where   date    < prev  
)
            -- the final result
select  c.*
from    err e
        inner join cte c    on  c.seq   >= e.seq - 1
                           and  c.seq   <= e.seq + 1
```

Comment: hi @Squirrel, how about if my tbl contain order by?

Comment: what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: if the with tbl as:  contain order by query? as im using this...select * from table order by trans id

Comment: table does not contains `ORDER BY`. `ORDER BY` is a clause / command that you tell `SQL Server` how you want the result return to arrange in particular sequence that you want.